# Silverlight 4: Chart

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, charts, silverlight-toolkit

Is it possible to create a multiple series points in silverlight chart toolkit just like with this [one](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1719731/chartmultipleseries.png)?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The toolkit charting does not currently do 3D perspective charts.  However it you are asking whether you can represent multiple columns series in a chart the answer is yes.  They will be represented in 2D columns side by side.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Anthony that the toolkit cannot help you much when it comes to showing 3D perspective. There are vendors that offer this functionality. You can take a look at [Telerik's 3D section](http://demos.telerik.com/silverlight/#Chart/Gallery3D/StackedBar).

Answer (score 0):

The current [toolkit](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/releases/view/78435) does not have 3D perspective charts.

However, Telerik does. They have a wide variety of 3D Charts that you can review at the links provided below:

**Bar Charts**

[3D Bar](http://demos.telerik.com/silverlight/#Chart/Gallery3D/Bar) , [3D Stacked Bar](http://demos.telerik.com/silverlight/#Chart/Gallery3D/StackedBar) , [3D Stacked Bar 100 Series](http://demos.telerik.com/silverlight/#Chart/Gallery3D/StackedBar100)

**Line Charts**

[3DLine](http://demos.telerik.com/silverlight/#Chart/Gallery3D/Line), [3D Stacked Line](http://demos.telerik.com/silverlight/#Chart/Gallery3D/StackedLine)

**Area Charts**

[3D Area](http://demos.telerik.com/silverlight/#Chart/Gallery3D/Area) , [3D Stacked Area](http://demos.telerik.com/silverlight/#Chart/Gallery3D/StackedArea) , [3D Stacked Area 100 Series](http://demos.telerik.com/silverlight/#Chart/Gallery3D/StackedArea100)

**Pie Charts**

[3D Doughnut](http://demos.telerik.com/silverlight/#Chart/Gallery3D/Doughnut) , [3D Pie](http://demos.telerik.com/silverlight/#Chart/Gallery3D/Pie)

Disclaimer: I work at Telerik as a XAML Evangelist.